# SAP oData Service - How to link two entity sets

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, sap-fiori, sap-gateway

In my first SAP fiori app I have created two entities in the odata Gateway in SAP backend. One for the main entity called 'Notification' and one for some value help field entity called 'Status'. Now I want to get the key of Notification when selecting the data for status entity so that each notification entity gets its individual Status value help depending on the key of the notification entity. How can i solve this?

Regards
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create an association for the two entities to connect them.
[image]

Comment: I thought about something similar but got two problems.

First i am not sure if this one helps me. As far as I understand the association is between the two entity sets or the two entities? But I need the key of entity Notification combined get transfered to the entity set of Status.

The second i did not get this work. I thought with creating the association the navigation table in get_entityset methods gets filled but in my case its always empty. Dont know why.

I also thought about creating deep entity but this also did not work for me until now.

Comment: This might be a helpful article https://sapcodes.com/2018/01/09/odata-association-and-navigation/